# Ionic 3: Menutoggle keeps getting hidden

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, hamburger-menu

I have implemented a hamburgermenu in Ionic 3, but I am facing an issue. When I run the application on my Android device the hamburgermenu keeps disappearing i.e. the button to open the side menu is gone. However, it only happens sometimes. I tried to run the application while inspecting it with Google Chrome, and what I noticed is that the menutoggle gets hidden for some reason, but I don't know why. I don't control the visibility in the .ts class.

```
<ion-header>
  <div>
    <ion-navbar>
      <button ion-button menuToggle> // this becomes "<button ion-button menuToggle hidden>"
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <ion-title>Frontpage</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </div>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution for it :(

Comment: same here. has anybody found a proper solution? Noticed that this only happens when the automatic back button appears.

Answer (score 4):

I am having similar issue for menu toggle.

I added below code for my page.

Header html code:

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-navbar text-center color="navBar">
  <ion-buttons right>
   <button class="menu" ion-button menuToggle="right" icon-only>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
   </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title>Password Reset</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Header css code:

```
.menu {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: this probably works but it's not the best solution. Have you found anything official on this?

Comment: Nope. I haven't found anything official.