# Not able to show the menu button in place of back button in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am working on the Ionic app and I have used navbar in my ionic app. When I move to other page, In place of menu button it is showing the back button. I don't want to show the back button, I always want to show the menu button in the navbar.

This is **page1.html**:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
    <button ion-button menuToggle start>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

It is only hiding the back button and not showing the menu button. I want to show the menu button in place of back button.

This is **page1.html**: Another Try.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar swipeBackEnabled="false">
    <button ion-button menuToggle start>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

This is not working. In this case, It is showing the back button.

This is **page1.ts**:

```
 ionViewWillEnter() {
  // Reset the content nav to have just this page
  // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(MerchandisePage);
 }
```

So I decided the make the page as a root page but It is continuously loading. This is not working.

This is my **page.html**:

```
<button (click)="merchandisepage2()" class="mybtn22" ion-button round>View All</button>
```

In this page, I have the button that will push to the other page.

This is my **page.ts**:

```
 movetopage1()
{
    this.navCtrl.push(Page1);
}
```

I don't want to show the back button, it should always show the menu button in the navbar. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with ionic when you have a custom button in the navbar and the page is not root.

You can find a quick fix here..

[Ionic 3: Menutoggle keeps getting hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50068182/ionic-3-menutoggle-keeps-getting-hidden)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that, set the page to the root page.

**page.ts**:

```
movetopage1()
{
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(Page1);
}
```

This is the method that comes in the **Ionic sidebar theme**.

This is the one that comes in the **Ionic sidebar theme**:

```
 openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
```